# What name spaces are there and what are the rules?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Note: this question is about `name space`, not `namespace`.

The C++ standard has some references to `name space`, but I don't see the definition of this. The standards says that labels and macros are in different name spaces. All the other references to `name space` are in the C/C++ compatibility section, like this ([current draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.class#1)):

> This is one of the few incompatibilities between C and C++ that can be attributed to the **new C++ name space definition** where a name can be declared as a type and as a non-type in a single scope causing the non-type name to hide the type name and requiring that the keywords class, struct, union or enum be used to refer to the type name. **This new name space definition** provides important notational conveniences to C++ programmers and helps making the use of the user-defined types as similar as possible to the use of fundamental types.

What is this *new name space definition*? Where can I find it in the standard? What are the exact rules? The rules seem to be more complicated, than "non-types hide types". Like, this doesn't compile:

```
typedef int Foo; // Foo is a type
void Foo();      // not a type, but compile error, instead of hiding
```

But this does:

```
struct Foo { }; // Foo is a type as well
void Foo();     // This hides the type Foo. "struct Foo" refers to the type
```

And this doesn't compile either:

```
struct Foo { };   // Type
namespace Foo { } // Non-type, but compiler error instead of hiding
```

Comment: The practical view is that a namespace is a singleton class with all-public members (subclasses). Please don't lynch me :-)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica read the question (again)

Comment: FWIW, your link links to the relevant sections: *Affected subclause: [class.name] [see also [dcl.typedef]]*  You can see those sections for how the rules work.

Comment: There is at least two name spaces: one for labels [`[stmt.label]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.label) and one for macros [`[cpp]/8`](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp#replace-8).

Comment: One for types (but _name space_ doesn't appear verbatim): [`[class.name]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name#2.sentence-1).

Comment: @YSC: Yep. If there were other mentions of "name space" for other things, I wouldn't have asked this question. But there are only two hits for "name space" (plus four in the C/C++ compatibility section), hence the question.

Comment: This is why I didn't put this into the answer section, this is not an answer.

Comment: @YSC: all right :)

Comment: It's somewhat interesting (to me) that both the description and the example show the opposite of what the rationale mentions; a type name hiding a non-type name. Given the draft status, I would expect that paragraph to change.

Answer (score 2):

The *name space* term may be more well-established in the ISO C Standard; citing [ISO C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers
>
> If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> - label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
> - the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any32) of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
> - the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member via the . or -> operator);
> - all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

The ***new** name space definition* of C++ is, however, not in any way *recent in time*, and has been described in [diff.class]/1 in its current form [ever since the ISO C++ Standard's introduction in '98](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/diff.html#diff.class). It's only ever mentioned in any length in the contexts for which it differs from ISO C, as per [diff.class]/1 which is quoted by the OP.

Afaics we need to resort to ISO C11/6.2.3 and combine it with [diff.class]/1 of the ISO C++ Standard for a cohesive and complete description of the *(new) name space definition of C++*, less we scourge the ISO C++ Standard for e.g. [[basic.scope.hiding]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.hiding), [[class.name]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name#2), [[stmt.label]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.label#1), [[cpp.replace]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.replace#8) and so on to see how and where it applies.

> **[class.name]/2**
>
> A class declaration introduces the class name into the scope where it is declared and hides any class, variable, function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope. [...]
>
> **[stmt.label]/1**
>
> [...] Labels have their own name space and do not interfere with other identifiers [...]
>
> **[cpp.replace]/1**
>
> [...] There is one name space for macro names. [...]

Answer (score 1):

In C (6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers) the notion of name spaces is defined the following way.

> 1 If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible
>   at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context
>   disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are
>   separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as
>   follows:
>
> — label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration
>   and use);
>
> — the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by
>   following any32) of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
>
> — the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a
>   separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the
>   expression used to access the member via the . or -> operator);
>
> — all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in
>   ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

So for example a structure tag name can coincide with a function name because they belong to different name spaces. When you specify a structure with a structure tag name when you have to use the keyword `struct`. So for example these declarations do not conflict.

```
struct s
{
    int s;
};

void s( void );

struct s s1;
```

In this code snippet the tag name `s` of the structure does not conflict with the function name `s`  because the tag name shall be specified with the keyword `struct`.

In C++ you are allowed to use structure tag names without the keyword `struct`.

For example

```
struct s
{
    int s;
};

s s;
```

is a correct code. In this declaration

```
s s;
```

the name of the declared identifier `s` hides the structure name. SO if then you will write for example

```
s s1;
```

then the compiler will issue an error because in this statement s is considered as the name of the identifier declared above. To resolve the ambiguity you need to use the keyword struct

```
struct s
{
    int s;
};

s s;

struct s s1;
```

This is described in the following quote from the C++ 20 Standard (6.3.1 Declarative regions and scopes)

> 4 Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
>   which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> (4.1) — they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to
>   functions and function templates; or
>
> (4.2) — exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or
>   enumeration name that is not a typedef name and the other declarations
>   shall all refer to the same variable, non-static data member, or
>   enumerator, or all refer to functions and function templates; in this
>   case the class name or enumeration name is hidden (6.3.10). [ **Note: A
>   namespace name or a class template name must be unique in its
>   declarative region (10.3.2, Clause 17). — end note** ]

As you can see from the quote a namespace name must be unique in its declarative region. So these declarations

```
struct Foo { };
namespace Foo { }
```

are incorrect.